# Dynamic Function Call for Prototype Functions

Tags: javascript

I have to make a bunch of `.prototype` declarations within a function and would like to add some *dynamism* to reduce the size of my code.

Here is some pseudo code for what I need to do:

```
window.myClass = function(){
  var object_type = getObjectType();
  if (object_type === 'NodeList')
  {
     NodeList.prototype.func_name = function(){
         //some code 
     }
  }

  if (object_type === 'HTMLCollection')
  {
     HTMLCollection.prototype.func_name = function(){
         //the same code again 
     }
  }
}
```

I would like to change this so I can make these declarations dynamic, kind of like this:

```
window.myClass = function(){
  var object_type = getObjectType();
  object_type.prototype.func_name = function(){
     //some code
  }
}
```

Is this possible?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that I would love to keep all my functions within the scope of `window.myClass`

Comment: What you should probably do is define these functions elsewhere, then assign them within the if conditions `if (object_type === 'HTMLCollection') { HTMLCollection.prototype.func_name = yourFunction; }` — that'll greatly improve readability.

Comment: By "dynamism" you mean using variables?

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can simply do

```
window[object_type].prototype[func_name] = function(){...
```

But be careful that you seem to be engaged in [modifying objects you don't own](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/). There's probably a better possible design for your application.

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer not to break scope from my initial object. I'm not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into details about what are you trying to accomplish or whether it's a good idea or there are better ways to do it, just based on your posted code, all you need to do is define "some code" as a funtion and assign it to whatever you want:

```
window.myClass = function(){
  function someCode() { /* some code */ }

  var object_type = getObjectType();
  if (object_type === 'NodeList')
  {
     NodeList.prototype.func_name = someCode;
  }

  if (object_type === 'HTMLCollection')
  {
     HTMLCollection.prototype.func_name = someCode;
  }
}
```

But you don't really need the if statement, because you can just do

```
window.myClass = function(){
  function someCode() { /* some code */ }

  var object_type = getObjectType();
  window[object_type].prototype.func_name = someCode;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I would not be comfortable with extending the window object (as your second code block suggests). Is there a way I can use this same bracket notation for things within the scope of my original object e.g. `[object_type].prototype.func_name`?

Comment: You're not extending the window object. You're adding a function to the prototype of something which is already on the window object.

Comment: So does that mean the code is encapsulated and there isn't any chance of collisions?

Comment: There is a chance of collisions if someone else adds the same method to the prototype of the same DOM class.